# ADB - Android - Getting the name of the current activity

Tags: android, adb, ddms

Is there a way to get the details of the current activity that is running via adb.

Comment: `this.getClass().getSimpleName()`

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can use this command,

```
adb shell dumpsys activity
```

You can find current activity name in activity stack.

**Output :-**

```
 Sticky broadcasts:
 * Sticky action android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED:
   Intent: act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000000
     Bundle[{icon-small=17302169, present=true, scale=100, level=50, technology=Li-ion, status=2, voltage=0, plugged=1, health=2, temperature=0}]
 * Sticky action android.net.thrott.THROTTLE_ACTION:
   Intent: act=android.net.thrott.THROTTLE_ACTION
     Bundle[{level=-1}]
 * Sticky action android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIMEZONE:
   Intent: act=android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIMEZONE flg=0x20000000
     Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=68]
 * Sticky action android.provider.Telephony.SPN_STRINGS_UPDATED:
   Intent: act=android.provider.Telephony.SPN_STRINGS_UPDATED flg=0x20000000
     Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=156]
 * Sticky action android.net.thrott.POLL_ACTION:
   Intent: act=android.net.thrott.POLL_ACTION
     Bundle[{cycleRead=0, cycleStart=1349893800000, cycleEnd=1352572200000, cycleWrite=0}]
 * Sticky action android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED:
   Intent: act=android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x20000000
     Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=116]
 * Sticky action android.intent.action.SIG_STR:
   Intent: act=android.intent.action.SIG_STR flg=0x20000000
     Bundle[{EvdoSnr=-1, CdmaDbm=-1, GsmBitErrorRate=-1, CdmaEcio=-1, EvdoDbm=-1, GsmSignalStrength=7, EvdoEcio=-1, isGsm=true}]
 * Sticky action android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE:
   Intent: act=android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE flg=0x20000000
     Bundle[{cdmaRoamingIndicator=0, operator-numeric=310260, networkId=0, state=0, emergencyOnly=false, operator-alpha-short=Android, radioTechnology=3, manual=false, cssIndicator=false, operator-alpha-long=Android, systemId=0, roaming=false, cdmaDefaultRoamingIndicator=0}]
 * Sticky action android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE:
   Intent: act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x30000000
     Bundle[{networkInfo=NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: simLoaded, extra: internet, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, reason=simLoaded, extraInfo=internet}]
 * Sticky action android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIME:
   Intent: act=android.intent.action.NETWORK_SET_TIME flg=0x20000000
     Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=36]
 * Sticky action android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED:
   Intent: act=android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED flg=0x70000000
     Bundle[{android.media.EXTRA_RINGER_MODE=2}]
 * Sticky action android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE:
   Intent: act=android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE flg=0x20000000
     Bundle[{state=CONNECTED, apnType=*, iface=/dev/omap_csmi_tty1, apn=internet, reason=simLoaded}]

 Activity stack:
 * TaskRecord{450adb90 #22 A org.chanakyastocktipps.com}
   clearOnBackground=false numActivities=2 rootWasReset=false
   affinity=org.chanakyastocktipps.com
   intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.SplashScreen}
   realActivity=org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.SplashScreen
   lastActiveTime=15107753 (inactive for 4879s)
   * Hist #2: HistoryRecord{450d7ab0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.Profile}
       packageName=org.chanakyastocktipps.com processName=org.chanakyastocktipps.com
       launchedFromUid=10046 app=ProcessRecord{44fa3450 1065:org.chanakyastocktipps.com/10046}
       Intent { cmp=org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.Profile }
       frontOfTask=false task=TaskRecord{450adb90 #22 A org.chanakyastocktipps.com}
       taskAffinity=org.chanakyastocktipps.com
       realActivity=org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.Profile
       base=/data/app/org.chanakyastocktipps.com-1.apk/data/app/org.chanakyastocktipps.com-1.apk data=/data/data/org.chanakyastocktipps.com
       labelRes=0x7f09000b icon=0x7f020065 theme=0x1030007
       stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true isHomeActivity=false
       configuration={ scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=3}
       resultTo=HistoryRecord{44f523c0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.MainScreen} resultWho=null resultCode=4
       launchFailed=false haveState=false icicle=null
       state=RESUMED stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
       keysPaused=false inHistory=true persistent=false launchMode=0
       fullscreen=true visible=true frozenBeforeDestroy=false thumbnailNeeded=false idle=true
       waitingVisible=false nowVisible=true
   * Hist #1: HistoryRecord{44f523c0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.MainScreen}
       packageName=org.chanakyastocktipps.com processName=org.chanakyastocktipps.com
       launchedFromUid=10046 app=ProcessRecord{44fa3450 1065:org.chanakyastocktipps.com/10046}
       Intent { cmp=org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.MainScreen }
       frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{450adb90 #22 A org.chanakyastocktipps.com}
       taskAffinity=org.chanakyastocktipps.com
       realActivity=org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.MainScreen
       base=/data/app/org.chanakyastocktipps.com-1.apk/data/app/org.chanakyastocktipps.com-1.apk data=/data/data/org.chanakyastocktipps.com
       labelRes=0x7f09000b icon=0x7f020065 theme=0x1030007
       stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true isHomeActivity=false
       configuration={ scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=3}
       launchFailed=false haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=1344]
       state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
       keysPaused=false inHistory=true persistent=false launchMode=0
       fullscreen=true visible=false frozenBeforeDestroy=false thumbnailNeeded=false idle=true
 * TaskRecord{450615a0 #2 A com.android.launcher}
   clearOnBackground=true numActivities=1 rootWasReset=false
   affinity=com.android.launcher
   intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
   realActivity=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
   lastActiveTime=12263090 (inactive for 7724s)
   * Hist #0: HistoryRecord{4505d838 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
       packageName=com.android.launcher processName=com.android.launcher
       launchedFromUid=0 app=ProcessRecord{45062558 129:com.android.launcher/10025}
       Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher }
       frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{450615a0 #2 A com.android.launcher}
       taskAffinity=com.android.launcher
       realActivity=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher
       base=/system/app/Launcher2.apk/system/app/Launcher2.apk data=/data/data/com.android.launcher
       labelRes=0x7f0c0002 icon=0x7f020044 theme=0x7f0d0000
       stateNotNeeded=true componentSpecified=false isHomeActivity=true
       configuration={ scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=3}
       launchFailed=false haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=3608]
       state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
       keysPaused=false inHistory=true persistent=false launchMode=2
       fullscreen=true visible=false frozenBeforeDestroy=false thumbnailNeeded=false idle=true

 Running activities (most recent first):
   TaskRecord{450adb90 #22 A org.chanakyastocktipps.com}
     Run #2: HistoryRecord{450d7ab0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.Profile}
     Run #1: HistoryRecord{44f523c0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.MainScreen}
   TaskRecord{450615a0 #2 A com.android.launcher}
     Run #0: HistoryRecord{4505d838 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}

 mPausingActivity: null
 mResumedActivity: HistoryRecord{450d7ab0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.Profile}
 mFocusedActivity: HistoryRecord{450d7ab0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.Profile}
 mLastPausedActivity: HistoryRecord{44f523c0 org.chanakyastocktipps.com/.ui.MainScreen}

 mCurTask: 22

 Running processes (most recent first):
   App  #13: adj=vis  /F 45052120 119:com.android.inputmethod.latin/10003 (service)
             com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME<=ProcessRecord{44ec2698 59:system/1000}
   PERS #12: adj=sys  /F 44ec2698 59:system/1000 (fixed)
   App  #11: adj=fore /F 44fa3450 1065:org.chanakyastocktipps.com/10046 (top-activity)
   App  #10: adj=bak  /B 44e7c4c0 299:com.svox.pico/10028 (bg-empty)
   App  # 9: adj=bak+1/B 450f7ef0 288:com.dreamreminder.org:feather_system_receiver/10057 (bg-empty)
   App  # 8: adj=bak+2/B 4503cc38 201:com.android.defcontainer/10010 (bg-empty)
   App  # 7: adj=home /B 45062558 129:com.android.launcher/10025 (home)
   App  # 6: adj=bak+3/B 450244d8 276:android.process.media/10002 (bg-empty)
   App  # 5: adj=bak+4/B 44f2b9b8 263:com.android.quicksearchbox/10012 (bg-empty)
   App  # 4: adj=bak+5/B 450beec0 257:com.android.protips/10007 (bg-empty)
   App  # 3: adj=bak+6/B 44ff37b8 270:com.android.music/10022 (bg-empty)
   PERS # 2: adj=core /F 45056818 124:com.android.phone/1001 (fixed)
   App  # 1: adj=bak+7/B 45080c38 238:com.dreamreminder.org/10057 (bg-empty)
   App  # 0: adj=empty/B 4507d030 229:com.android.email/10030 (bg-empty)

 PID mappings:
   PID #59: ProcessRecord{44ec2698 59:system/1000}
   PID #119: ProcessRecord{45052120 119:com.android.inputmethod.latin/10003}
   PID #124: ProcessRecord{45056818 124:com.android.phone/1001}
   PID #129: ProcessRecord{45062558 129:com.android.launcher/10025}
   PID #201: ProcessRecord{4503cc38 201:com.android.defcontainer/10010}
   PID #229: ProcessRecord{4507d030 229:com.android.email/10030}
   PID #238: ProcessRecord{45080c38 238:com.dreamreminder.org/10057}
   PID #257: ProcessRecord{450beec0 257:com.android.protips/10007}
   PID #263: ProcessRecord{44f2b9b8 263:com.android.quicksearchbox/10012}
   PID #270: ProcessRecord{44ff37b8 270:com.android.music/10022}
   PID #276: ProcessRecord{450244d8 276:android.process.media/10002}
   PID #288: ProcessRecord{450f7ef0 288:com.dreamreminder.org:feather_system_receiver/10057}
   PID #299: ProcessRecord{44e7c4c0 299:com.svox.pico/10028}
   PID #1065: ProcessRecord{44fa3450 1065:org.chanakyastocktipps.com/10046}

 mHomeProcess: ProcessRecord{45062558 129:com.android.launcher/10025}
 mConfiguration: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=3}
 mConfigWillChange: false
 mSleeping=false mShuttingDown=false
```

Comment: Can be even better if you use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`

Comment: This is good info. Some applications have pop-up windows. How can you tell if a pop-up window is on the top?

Answer (score 224):

I prefer parsing results of `dumpsys window windows` over `dumpsys activity`

```
adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"
```

Keyguard or Recent tasks list used to not show up as Activities but you were able to see them with `mCurrentFocus`. I have explained why in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39774220/1778421).

**Edit note:**

- `grep` is a command-line utility for Unix-like operating systems such as Linux, macOS, and Android. For Windows users, it's important to use quotes: "" or `` or '' for the command after the `adb shell`. With the quotes, the `grep` command will be passed into `adb shell` and will be processed inside Android rather than the host OS.
- Without the quotes, the `adb shell dumpsys window windows` command will output everything, and then it will be piped into `grep` in your OS. But with the quotes, `"dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"`, the piping process happens inside Android, which makes it work in Windows.
- Although the result will be the same in Unix-like OS, executing the command without quotes multiple times - consecutively - will eventually result in a slower process over time.

Comment: `$ adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
  mCurrentFocus=
  mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{40b11d40 token=HistoryRecord{ }}`

Current focus is empty. Any idea? My device is connected,App is running, it is 2.3 device

Comment: that how I can find which app is randomly showing ads without my permission! thank you!

Comment: `adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on android 29, as neither of these fields now appear in the window dump

Comment: I tried `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mObscuringWindow'` and it worked on Android 29

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp|mInputMethodTarget|mSurface'` works for all android versions

Comment: `mInputMethodTarget` is the only one that worked for me on Android 11, Samsung UI. Thanks @prince!

Comment: On Android 11, one should replace `windows` with `displays`, to find mCurrentFocus. Or one can just omit `windows` altogether and it should work on more devices.

Comment: 获取当前activity，这可太牛逼了

Comment: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys window | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'` like @alexander-pruss suggests works well in sdk 31

Comment: Empty result using this command

Answer (score 90):

Android Q broke most of these for me.  Here's a new one that seems to be working (at least on Android Q).

```
adb shell "dumpsys activity activities | grep mResumedActivity"
```

Output looks like:

```
mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{7f6df99 u0 com.sample.app/.feature.SampleActivity t92}
```

Edit: Works on Android R for me as well

Comment: This worked on my S10 running Android Q

`adb shell 'dumpsys activity activities | grep ResumedActivity'`

Comment: Worked on S10 Lite.

Comment: What about the case where I'd like to browse through the stack of activities, not just a resumed one?

Comment: To get just the package name, the above can extended and used -> (not the most efficient logic, but gets the task done)

`adb shell "dumpsys activity activities | grep mResumedActivity" |  cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d " " -f3 | cut -d "/" -f1`

Answer (score 29):

[`dumpsys window windows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13212310/3063884) gives more detail about the current activity:

```
adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"
  mCurrentFocus=Window{41d2c970 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
  mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{4203c170 token=Token{41b77280 ActivityRecord{41b77a28 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher t3}}}
```

However in order to find the process ID (e.g. to kill the current activity), use [`dumpsys activity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13193626/3063884), and grep on "top-activity":

```
adb shell "dumpsys activity | grep top-activity"
    Proc # 0: fore  F/A/T  trm: 0 3074:com.android.launcher/u0a8 (top-activity)

adb shell "kill 3074"
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want to filter out only your app's activities currently running/paused, you can use this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep 'Hist #' | grep 'YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME'
```

For example:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep 'Hist #' | grep 'com.supercell.clashroyale'
```

The output will be something like:

```
* Hist #2: ActivityRecord{26ba44b u10 com.supercell.clashroyale/StartActivity t27770}
* Hist #1: ActivityRecord{2f3a0236 u10 com.supercell.clashroyale/SomeActivity t27770}
* Hist #0: ActivityRecord{20bbb4ae u10 com.supercell.clashroyale/OtherActivity t27770}
```

Do notice that the output shows the actual stack of activities i.e. the topmost activity is the one that is currently being displayed.

Comment: Best answer so far. Show the stack, exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

`adb shell dumpsys activity`

And this to show current activity name:

`adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedActivity | cut -d . -f 5 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

For a more accurate script to get the activity name, see [this](https://github.com/hpedrorodrigues/sphynx/blob/f71a00b5af06ec2af3e3d353f2bdfce6c23cf7b5/cli/android/core/activity.sh).

Comment: Nice, this just displays the simple name of the activity.  No other info.  But useful.

Answer (score 16):

Old answers stopped working in new android versions. Now I use the following:

```
adb shell "dumpsys activity activities | grep ResumedActivity"
```

Comment: i use this `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep "mCurrentFocus"` for android 10

Answer (score 8):

You can try this command,

```
adb shell dumpsys activity recents
```

There you can find current activity name in activity stack.

To get most recent activity name:

```
adb shell dumpsys activity recents | find "Recent #0"
```

Comment: For anyone else looking to do this from a terminal on the device (i.e. with Terminal Emulator or Automagic), `dumpsys activity recents | grep "Recent #0"` will get the line of output with the most recent activity name. (It has to be done as root.)

Comment: Error: `find: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 7):

`adb shell dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedApp` works for me.

`adb shell "dumpsys activity activities | grep mResumedActivity"` does not work for me for my device: `Google Pixel 4 Android 12, API 32`

```
adb shell "dumpsys activity activities | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"
```

works for me as well.

Comment: this solutions works on Android 13 for me

Answer (score 5):

In windows, this command works for me to show current activity name

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | find "mCurrentFocus"
```

Output:

```
mCurrentFocus=Window{a43a55b u0 com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.TwelveKeyDialer}
```

Other solutions with "grep" command produce error in my windows pc

```
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So, using "find" solve the error in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Below command can be used for finding both package and current Activity name. Found this  very useful command to quickly fetch these two information about an app especially when developing tests with Appium.

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'
```

Response of this command contains both package name and current Activity. For example: in following "com.android.contacts" is the package and "com.android.contacts.activities.TwelveKeyDialer" is current Activity launched on the phone which is connected via adb.

```
mCurrentFocus=Window{2089af8 u0 com.android.contacts/com.android.contacts.activities.TwelveKeyDialer}
```

Reference: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that is easier than the command line adb solution (which does work).  It is easier because it is more graphical and can be done from within Eclipse.

In Eclipse with Android device attached go to Window menu > Show View > Other ... use filter text "Windows" to pull up Android > Windows ... show this.  The top item in the list is the current activity.

Another way to pull this up is by showing the "Hierarchy View" perspective, which by default will show the Windows window.

Answer (score 2):

#### Stack of current activities

```bash
adb shell dumpsys activity top | grep "ACTIVITY"
```

Result:

```bash
ACTIVITY com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity 637831e pid=1795
ACTIVITY com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity a2ca51d pid=1053
ACTIVITY com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivityGmail 621126d pid=28250
```

#### Activity in the foreground, currently visible

```bash
adb shell dumpsys activity top | grep "ACTIVITY" | tail -n 1
```

Result:

```bash
ACTIVITY com.google.android.gm/.ConversationListActivityGmail 621126d pid=28250
```

#### Only the foreground activity name

```bash
adb shell dumpsys activity top | grep "ACTIVITY" | tail -n 1 | sed -E 's/.*\/([^ ]+).*/\1/'
```

Result:

```bash
.ConversationListActivityGmail
```

#### Only the foreground app name

```bash
adb shell dumpsys activity top | grep "ACTIVITY" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f1
```

Result:

```bash
com.google.android.gm
```

Answer (score 1):

My version which works for Linux and Windows:

```
adb shell "dumpsys activity activities | grep mResumedActivity | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d "/" -f1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Dump **current activity** that works with Android 12 / 13

```
adb shell dumpsys activity | awk -F '[ /}]' '/mCurrentFocus/{print $9}'
```

Grep

```
adb shell dumpsys activity | grep -oP 'mCurrentFocus=\S+ \S+ \K\S+(?=})'
```