# How to test if the app has crashed from a monkeyrunner script?

Tags: android, adb, monkeyrunner

I use the Android `monkeyrunner` tool to test my app with a script that is mostly the one from the tutorial:

```py
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
device.installPackage('the-app.apk')
device.startActivity(component="package.app.the/package.app.the.Main")

# then pilot the app
```

At the end of this script I would like to test if the app is still running or if it has crashed (i.e. the "App has stopped" message is displayed).

I tried to [get the info by checking the PID of the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691487/how-to-detect-running-app-using-adb-command):

```py
pid = device.shell('pidof package.app.the')
```

Unfortunately there is a valid pid returned by this command. I thought it was because I checked too soon so I tried to put a `MonkeyRunner.sleep(10)` before it. The result is the same, it seems that the app is still running while the "App has stopped" popup is displayed.

I also tried to parse the output of `device.shell('ps -A')` but the result is the same: the app is running.

Then I tried to send key events with `device.press("BACK", MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)` in an attempt to dismiss the "App has stopped" dialog but the dialog stayed.

Now I'm out of ideas. How to test if the app has crashed from the script?

Comment: does the answer below help you in figuring out the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Python, my suggestion is to use [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and automate the process of detecting the string ids contained the the "App has stopped" dialog. An example might be this [one](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/click-no-id-button.py).

For instance, the "App has stopped" textview has resource-id `android:id/alertTitle` whereas the button ("Open the app again") has resource-id `android:id/aerr_restart`.

Comment: [AdbClient.getTopActivityNameAndPid()](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py#L1338) would also help determine if the activity is still on top