# How to kill any android applications from a terminal shortcut?

Tags: android

I have this new app that I got from the Play store which allows me to make shortcuts for certain actions. For my likings, I want to make it so that if I hold the volume up button, it would kill the app. (Not minimize, but kill). It doesn't have that option but it does have an option to have a terminal emulation shortcut.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: This looks like it may help.. 


http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45202/terminal-or-adb-command-to-force-stop-application

Comment: @jmejiaa but you would need a package name for that. I just want it so that when I press the button, the app that is currently open will be killed.

Comment: Get the current package name like so.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193592/adb-android-getting-the-name-of-the-current-activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### killing the app:

```
  adb shell am kill com.myapp.package
```

#### stopping the app using adb:

```
  adb shell am force-stop com.myapp.package
```

more info:

**https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#am**

Comment: Do i enter this in terminal on my android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `am force-stop <package name> and  am kill <package name>`