# adb shell dumpsys window windows output describing

Tags: android, adb, appium, android-shell, dumpsys

I'm using [appium](http://appium.io/) for interaction between my Android device and java code. And I faced with problem that on some kind of devices(including emulators) after pressing on Home button, appium return incorrect current activity (it returns previous activity which is currently must be minimized). I found that appium used [`dumpsys window windows`](https://github.com/appium/appium-adb/blob/01c77966d846e8ce79582d767ac4d17120c32957/lib/tools/apk-utils.js#L89)  with grabbing `mFocusedApp` value for getting current app. I read [another answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193592/adb-android-getting-the-name-of-the-current-activity) about getting Android current activities, and mostly it recommend to use:

```
adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"
```

That was the source of the problem, because after pressing Home button `mCurrentFocus` and `mFocusedApp` linked to different activities. But I can't find any explanation the difference between these fields. And why appium uses only `mFocusedApp` for it?

Comment: The question *why appuim uses only `mFocusedApp`?* calls for speculation and is an off-topic here.

Answer (score 10):

The *explanation of the difference* between `mCurrentFocus` and `mFocusedApp` stares right at you:

```
$ dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
    mCurrentFocus=Window{X uX package/.activity}
    mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{X token=Token{X ActivityRecord{X uX package/.activity tX}}}
```

The `mCurrentFocus` is a `Window` (just a `view` which may or may not have an `ActivityRecord` associated with it)

The `mFocusedApp` is an `AppWindowToken` (an `app` `Token` which will always have an `ActivityRecord`)

So when input focus switches to a `view` with an `activity` - both `mCurrentFocus` and `mFocusedApp` would show the same `activity`. But sometimes focus switches to a `view` without an `activity` (like parts of SystemUI, etc) - then `mCurrentFocus` will be showing that `view` but `mFocusedApp` will still be showing the `ActivityRecord` of the `app` which had the focus before the last switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
For windows:

```
adb shell dumpsys window | find "mCurrentFocus"
```

For MAC:

```
adb shell dumpsys window | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'
```