# Android 7 app intelligent power saving?

Tags: android, android-service, background-process, android-7.0-nougat

I bought a new phone (Lava A44) to test my app on Nougat.  It has a feature in Battery settings that does not seem to be explained in Android docs (see screenshot below):

[image]

I am using Handler#postDelayed() in my app and it works fine when in foreground and after sometime the app stops getting FCM messages and does not fire the postDelayed unless I turn off "App freezer" and Synchronous wake-up" as shown in the picture.

Somehow these settings are found to be Off by default for WhatsApp and Facebook.

As suggested in other posts, I have tried AlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(), ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, PowerManager#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations, but to no avail. This seems to be some manufacturer specific customization to Android N.

My questions are:

1. is there a way I can navigate my user to the above screen (second),
   so i can request him to turn them off?
2. is it possible to find out what intent it is (using adb logs or otherwise) so that I can navigate the user to it?
3. any other ideas to work around this?

**Edit:**
I tried cricket_007's comment below and below is adb output:

```
Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{c79fa27 #421 A=com.android.settings U=0 StackId=1 sz=4}
    Run #5: ActivityRecord{b7bd3c3 u0 com.android.lava.powersave/.ui.SmartAppManagerSettinsActivity t421}
    Run #4: ActivityRecord{a55162f u0 com.android.lava.powersave/.ui.SmartAppManagerActivity t421}
    Run #3: ActivityRecord{c91700c u0 com.android.lava.powersave/.ui.LavaPowerSaveManager t421}
    Run #2: ActivityRecord{b60d04d u0 com.android.settings/.Settings t421}
```

It does seem to be a manufacturer specific customization, so I can't open the screen from my app.  From other posts, it appears even Samsung phones have such feature. Any ideas of detecting or opening such screen for a generic case?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193592/adb-android-getting-the-name-of-the-current-activity

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately it seems to be a manufacturer specific screen (com.android.lava.powersave/.ui.SmartAppManagerSettinsActivity). I can't open manufacturer specific screen as my app targets all devices.. :-(