# dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus' command is not giving me any result

Tags: adb, appium, appium-android, dumpsys

I am giving `dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus | mFocusedApp'` command in the command prompt and it is not giving any results.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPb0u.png)

Comment: Make sure ADB is setup properly. Please make sure too that you open the app before use command, because command would provide the details only for the app which is currently in focus. Try this without Pipe .....  dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus’

Comment: you should have copied the command verbatim https://stackoverflow.com/a/13212310/1778421

Comment: also please do not post text as images

Comment: remove space character between 'mCurrentFocus' and '|' and  'mFocusedApp'. you must use 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp' instead of 'mCurrentFocus | mFocusedApp'

Answer (score 4):

On my Android 11 device, using `dumpsys window windows` doesn't give the currently focused window. Instead one has to do:

`dumpsys window displays | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`

I think a solution that works on all devices is:

`dumpsys window | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`

(`dumpsys window` dumps information about all the subtopics, including windows and displays).

Comment: this works on pixel 7 android 13. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra spaces:

```
dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.
`dumpsys window | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For windows you can easily find out app package and app activity below this command: open cmd in your PC

1. adb devices
2. adb shell dumpsys window | find "mCurrentFocus"